# Invoking methods of a function-object given to a raphael object constructor as a callback function

Tags: javascript, raphael

My application has similar structure to the example below. I need interface to create canvases dynamically. As I create these raphael objects I give them canvasActions as parameter.

If I create new canvas-object with the createCanvas-method the object set to canvases-table is of type Raphael and seems I can't use the canvasActions assigned to it. So the problem is I can't use methods in interface returned by canvasActions-function.

What changes do I have to make in order to invoke methods assigned to a particular Raphael object?

```
var myApp = (function() {
    var canvasActions = function() {

        var actionInterface = function() {
            //returns interface object
        }();

        return actionInterface;
    }

    var myAppInterface = function {
        var canvases = [];
        var appInterface = {
            createCanvas: function(contextElementId, width, height) {
                 canvases[canvases.length] = Raphael(contextElementId, width, height, canvasActions);
            },
            getCanvas: function(index) {
                return canvases[index]; 
            }
        }
        return appInterface;
    }();

    return myAppInterface;

}());
```

Answer (score 1):

the `callback` parameter is just that - a callback method invoked once the document is ready. it is not meant to be referred and used otherwise.

if you wish to add functionality to the `paper`, use `Raphael.fn` to augment the built in functions of the `Raphael` object.

**Example:**

```js
Raphael.fn.canvasActions = {
    move: function () {
        // ...
    },
    repaint: function () {
        // ...
    }
    // etc.
};

// ...

appInterface.getCanvas(5).canvasActions.repaint();
```

**References:**

- [`Raphael()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael)
- [`Raphael.fn()`](http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael.fn)

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you're not having problems with having `canvasActions()` referring to the wrong instance, but that you're simply having problems calling `canvasActions` at all once you've placed it into the Raphael object. Is that correct?

I'm not at all familiar with Raphael.  But I wanted to give you a better answer.  However, when I look through the docs, I don't see a 4th parameter callback being used anywhere in Raphael constructors.  Instead, I always see this:

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
```

If you are not able to use a callback defined by Raphael, then you could always add your own, like so (substituting paper with your indexed array):

```
var paper = new Raphael(document.getElementById('canvas_container'), 500, 500);
paper.performActions = canvasActions;
```

Then, you should be able to use:

```
myApp.getCanvas(0).performActions();
```

Comment: Thank you for answer, but this doesn't seem to solve my problem.

Comment: Yes, I can't call canvasActions after they've been placed into Raphael object. 

btw. Raphael documentation (http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Paper.path) states that there can be 4 parameters and 4th is callback. I will make more test with ideas your answer gave and hopefully I manage to solve this.

Comment: link to the correct position on raphael reference: http://raphaeljs.com/reference.html#Raphael

Comment: If you just do Raphael('id',300,300,function() { alert('called back'); } ); do you ever get an alert?